# How do I optionally specify parameters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm porting some old code from AutoHotkey 'for laughs' and think I've stumbled across an unintended feature it had...

I'm wanting to be able to do something 'like'

```
$ws = "Minimized"
$parameters = "/k dir F:\" 
start-process cmd.exe ( $(if($parameters){"-argumentlist $parameters"}) )( $(if ($ws){"-windowystyle $ws"}) )
```

But it never 'concatenates' them into the one command 'holistically' without *also* throwing them all at cmd.exe - I'm naively hoping Powershell can 'catch' the WindowStyle itself, for example, and minimize the window (currently, it's passed straight to cmd.exe which ignores it).

I know I'm a bit mad, but I'm also struggling to find the right terms to search for - about_parsing wasn't helpful and the bazillion examples of concatenating strings is no good either - I'm really wanting Powershell to be loose enough to allow me to switch from strings to parameters dynamically, which I'm guessing goes against a conscious design decision somewhere...

So the alternative is a bunch of if statements to accommodate the various permutations of options...

```
if ($ws -and -(not $parameters)) {start-process cmd.exe -windowystyle $ws}
if ($parameters -and -(not $ws)) {start-process cmd.exe -argumentlist $parameters}
if ($parameters -and $ws) {start-process cmd.exe -argumentlist $parameters -windowystyle $ws}
...ad nauseum
```

Unless someone's got any better ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem with your "like" example is that it's grouping everything that comes after `cmd.exe` and passing it to `Start-Process` as a single-string second positional parameter which is `ArgumentList`. So you're effectively running this:

```perl
Start-Process -FilePath 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList "-argumentlist /k dir F:\ -windowstyle Minimized"
```

[Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) might help you out a bit here. You can use a hashtable to dynamically build the set of parameters that get sent before you actually call `Start-Process`. For example:

```perl
# initialize a hashtable we'll use to splat with later
# that has all of the params that will always be used.
# (it can also be empty)
$startParams = @{
    FilePath = 'cmd.exe'
}

# conditionally add your WindowStyle
if ($ws) {
    $startParams.WindowStyle = $ws
}

# conditionally add your ArgumentList
if ($parameters) {
    $startParams.ArgumentList = $parameters
}

# run the function with the splatted hashtable
Start-Process @startParams
```

Comment: You legend - thanks, I knew it was possible but just hadn't grasped what the fix was.  Works beautifully.
I figured out $startParams.Wait = $true works as well (for parameters that don't actually have a value, but are switches)